# Limits using substitution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I'm trying to solve this exercise, could you tell me if I'm right?

$\lim\limits_{x \to h} \frac{\cos x-\cos h}{x-h}=\frac{0}{0}$

let $z=x-h$ ;  $z+h=x$

$\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{\cos(z+h)-\cos h}{z}=\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{\cos(z)\cos(h)-\sin(z)\sin(h)-\cos(h)}{z}=\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{-\cos(h)+\cos(z)\cos(h)-\sin(z)\sin(h)}{z}=\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{\cos(h)[\cos(z)-1]-\sin(z)\sin(h)}{z}=\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{\cos(h)[\cos(z)-1]}{z}-\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{\sin(z)\
sin(h)}{z}=-\sin(h)$

Comment: Yes, that is correct. What you ended up with is essentially just the difference quotient of $\cos x$ evaluated $x=h$, which is why the result is the derivative of $\cos x$.

Comment: what is the approach to the derivative? I still don't see that topic @Tham

Comment: Rest assured that your substitution and your final answer is correct. I was just trying to point out that after your substitution, you ended up with a [difference quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient); and by taking $z\to0$, what your limit does is, by definition, the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Definition) at $x=h$. So your final answer should be the same as $\frac{d}{dx}\cos x\Big|_{x=h} = -\sin h$, which is precisely what you got.

Comment: Alternative is L'Hopital's rule: As $x \to h, ~\frac{\cos(x) - \cos(h)}{x - h}$ does evaluate to $\frac{0}{0}.$  Then, taking the derivative of the numerator and denominator separately (with respect to the variable $x$), you have that as $x \to h$, the fraction goes to $\lim_{x\to h}\frac{-\sin(x)}{1} = -\sin(h).$

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's correct, as an alternative directly by [sum to product formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)

$$\frac{\cos x-\cos h}{x-h}=\frac{-2\sin\left(\frac{x+h}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-h}2\right)}{x-h}=-\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x-h}2\right)}{\frac{x-h}2}\sin\left(\frac{x+h}2\right)\to -\sin h$$